# Laravel log file specific to a package

Tags: php, laravel, monolog

I'm writing a couple of laravel packages and I'm wondering if it is possible to have the package write to a specific log file but only for messages related to the package?

I tried making a logging.php file in the packages/myorg/mypackage/config (below) but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
use Monolog\Handler\NullHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\SyslogUdpHandler;

return [
    'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),
    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['single'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/mypackage.log'),
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
        ]
    ]
];
```

I am using "jeroen-g/laravel-packager" to set up the packages. It appears to manually load the mypackage.config in the ServiceProvider bootForConsole

```
protected function bootForConsole(): void
{
    // Publishing the configuration file.
    $this->publishes([
        mypackage.'/../config/mypackage.php' => config_path('mypackage.php'),
    ], 'mypackage.config');
}
```

I'm not sure how to add custom logging to that though. I'm still learning Laravel and I'm not quite sure what or how the main applications config/logging.php is read so I'm not quite sure how to inject a custom version for an add-on package.

EDIT:
I found a post that suggested using the following in the ServiceManager boot() method:

```
$this->app->make('config')->set('logging.channels.mychannel', [
    /* settings */
]);
```

I used the package config to set a 'logging' => [ 'channels' => [ 'mychannel' => [ /* settings */ ] ] ] and could then do the same thing as above with:

```
$this->app->make('config')->set('logging.channels.mychannel', config('mypackage.logging.channels.mychannel');
```

But that still required something in the code.  The next best thing I have found thus far is to change my config/logging.php to config/logging.channels.php and include something like:

```
return [
    'mychannel' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/mypackage.log'),
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
    ]
];
```

Then in the service provider register() method add:

```
    $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__ . '/../config/logging.channels.php', 'logging.channels');
```

I tried doing it from the original 'logging.php' with channels array nested in a 'logging' key, but array_merge doesn't appear to merge the nested elements so my channel never showed up in logging.channels.

I'm not sure if this is ideal, however.  I'd still like to know if there is a 'better' or best practices way of adding custom package logging parameters and whether there is a need to publish it in any way (and how).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward way to have your custom package perform some logging into the target application's `storage/logging` directory.

In the package I define a `config/logging.php` that mirrors laravels default logging config file, but with only a single channel defined (adjust as necessary for your package requirements):

```php
return [
    'channels' => [
        'my-package' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/my-package.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'days' => 7,
        ],
    ],
];
```

In the service provider for your custom package you need to merge in the package's custom logging channel(s) into the target application config:

```php
public function register()
{
    // Merge any of your default package config (as needed)
    $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__ . '/../config/my-package.php', 'my-package');

    // Next we specifically merge the logging channels provided by this package
    $this->mergeLoggingChannels();

    // ...
}

private function mergeLoggingChannels()
{
    // This is the custom package logging configuration we just created earlier
    $packageLoggingConfig = require __DIR__ . '/../config/logging.php';

    $config = $this->app->make('config');

    // For now we manually merge in only the logging channels. We could also merge other logging config here as well if needed.
    // We do this merging manually since mergeConfigFrom() does not do a deep merge and we want to merge only the channels array
    $config->set('logging.channels', array_merge(
        $packageLoggingConfig['channels'] ?? [],
        $config->get('logging.channels', [])
    ));
}
```

`composer require` your package into your target application.

Within the target application run `php artisan config:cache` and then `php artisan tinker`

Print the contents of `config('logging.channels')` and you should now see your package's logging channel in the resulting array

You can log to this channel from the target application or from within the package itself with `Log::channel('my-package')->info('Hello world')`